# Notepad++ and delimiters: automatically replace ``string'' by \command{string}

Tags: regex, string, replace, notepad++

Within Notepad++, I want to replace many instances of the type ``` ``string'' ``` by `\command{string}` where `string` can be any string of characters. I am fairly close to what I want to achieve with:

```
Find: (?<=``)(.*?)(?='')
Replace: \\command{\1}
```

There is still a problem. With the regex code above, instead of `\command{string}` I get ``` ``\command{string}'' ``` and I am not sure why the ``` `` ``` and `''` are not removed?

Comment: I think NP++ does not support lookahead/behind (unfortunatelly, as `(?!NotThis)` is very handy.

Comment: NP++ does support these features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are using lookaround assertions. [Lookaround (`zero-width`) assertions](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html) only assert that a position can be matched and do not "consume" any characters on the string. You can use the below regular expression.

```
Find: ``([^']+)''
Replace: \\command{\1}
```

Comment: I would use `[^']+` instead of `.*` (and I am not sure what `?)` does.

Comment: @eckes The `?` binds the other side, it modifies the `*`. The sequence `.*` matches zero or more of any character and it is a **greedy** match. The sequence `.*?` also matches zero or more of any character but it is a **non greedy** match. Web searching for greedy and non greedy matches should explain the fine details.

Comment: @AdrianHHH this does not work in my NP++ version. The RE is (as Posix defined) greedy, but `.*?` does not match for me.

Comment: Looks like you have an outdated version because it clearly supports PCRE

Comment: @eckes Notepad++ version 5.9.6.2 is quite old. Notepad++ version 6.6.9 appear to be the latest version.

Comment: @AdrianHHH strange, that was the version i downloaded --- I guess from the wrong site. Anyway, with this version it works... now loading 6.6.9. Thanks. http://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap everything into a capture group and use that. NP++ seems to not support lookahead/behind, but you dont need that for this specific case anyway:

```
``([^']+)'' -> \\command{\1}
```

This will make sure it does not match two commands (longest match) in something like:

```
run ``ls -l'' or ``ls -a''
```

Comment: Thanks. If I am correct, your first method does the same as mine and the second does \command{``string''}.